# pycharm no "run" button

Tags: python, pycharm

Installed PyCharm on the new windows10.
If i create a new project everything works ok - all buttons on the places.
But if i run ANY .py file associated with pycharm i see just the code and no Run or configure buttons. There is also no indexing\something bar at the bottom. I've waited for couple hours and nothing changed.

The same thing on new linux.

What am i doing wrong?
(i also can't rightclick the file cuz 'nothing here' appears)

[as you can see - no buttons..?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEA7u.jpg)

Comment: You can run only if you have added the top level script environment - https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html

Comment: How can i add it?

Comment: You can use the example quoted in my comment earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you started PyCharm in the light edit mode (see https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/04/lightedit-mode/), try to run PyCharm first and then create project on top of your directory or just open this directory.

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm associated all .py to edit, you will open the source code.
To run, try "right click" and search for "RUN" or click "CTRL+SHIFT+F10"

Answer (score 0):

[image: EDIT]This is because when you install Pycharm and start with new scratch file, Pycharm doesn't know which file you want to run so you can see Run. To Run your script **Right-Click** in the space and then click on Run. After this you will get a Run button in the top-right of the corner.

Hope it helps!

Comment: ctrl+shift+f10 doesn't work
and i don't know there is "space" to rightclick it. 
screenshots attached:
https://imgur.com/im11Q5Z
https://imgur.com/o1excsk

Comment: imgur.com/im11Q5Z
at this screenshot i rightclick this area - nothing

Comment: i does't give a pop up like above??

Comment: only what I have in the screenshot

Comment: which screnshot mine or yours??

Comment: Goto Run in Navigation Bar above and see if you have Run there

Comment: Nothing there to run it. Only New-open-save-exit.
It's like a notepad window. I can edit it, but cannot run.

Comment: See this from 05:00 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZUNUB6nz3g&t=345s

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the jetbrain tutorial on how to open/hide a navigation bar.
 [Use the navigation bar](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/part-4-using-the-navigation-bar.html#)

Comment: As you can see on my screenshot there is no such button to expand the navigation bar. I also can't use alt+shift+S 
Have no idea whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that at some point you accidentally reassigned the "*.py" file name pattern in PyCharm to another category than "Python".

Go to File->Settings->Editor->File types and look for "*.py". Remove it from the found category and add it to "Python". Restart PyCharm.

In the end, make sure that the "*.py" file name pattern is an active pattern in category "Python".
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzFGO.png)